# TFS 2010: WorkItem.Save triggers WorkItemChangedEvent again

Tags: tfs, event-handling

I better start off by explaining a high level overview of what I'm trying to do (just in case I'm going about this horribly wrong): In TFS, we have a "Story" workitem that includes a "priority" field. At any given time we have maybe 20-30 stories that have a priority. As an example, we might have 20 perfectly prioritized stories (1 through 20), and then want to create a new story that should be our new top priority. So, I want to be able to give it a priority of 1, and then have a server-side plugin that will update the priority on all of the other stories so that I end up with 1 through 21 (1 being the new story we just created).

To this end, I've created a server-side plugin for TFS 2010 that subscribes to WorkItemChangedEvent. It's smart enough to figure out if the priority was updated, so it only changes workitems in this case. The problem I run into is that if I alter the priority and run WorkItem.Save(), it triggers WorkItemChangedEvent again, and the priority has changed, so the logic is true, and it updates and saves again.

Earlier, I had created a server-side plugin that updated the time on one of the datetime fields to 00:00:00 (in the case that it wasn't already 00:00:00) and noticed this behavior. It wasn't TOO big of a problem, because on the second run through, nothing would happen because the time would already be 00:00:00. But in this case of trying to update the priorities on a whole bunch of work items, it's a deal-breaker. Is there a way to stop WorkItem.Save() from triggering a WorkItemChangedEvent? Maybe another way to go about doing this altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way I know would solve this is to add a specific comment and then to to check the comment/history item of the work item to see that you last updated it as part of the change you're doing.

Also, check out the following [post for pointers on how to create your service so that it remains stable](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/assafstone/archive/2011/07/29/how-to-write-a-robust-tfs-server-plugin-with-job-extensions.aspx).

Comment: I'll mark this as an answer if nobody comes up with a better solution. It will work, but it's too bad if there's not a cleaner way.

Comment: sure i hope for a better solution as well. maybe you can find something in the sources of the tfs aggregator http://tfsaggregator.codeplex.com/

Comment: I ended up going this route in the interest of time. I had to do one save where I updated the priority field as well as a boolean field, then the handler can ignore any case where the boolean is true. Then I did a second save where I set the boolean back to false. In that case the priority hasn't changed so, again, nothing happens.

Comment: Was afraid it would be the only answer. It's how Microsoft also uses the ***_NOCI_*** on builds to prevent triggering another automated build after commit.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue in my own extension by checking if the changer identity is the service identity. If it is then the logic is skipped.

This seems like a slightly more elegant solution then tagging the data.

```
var workItemChangedArgs = notificationEventArgs as WorkItemChangedEvent;
var identityService = requestContext.GetService<IdentityService>();
var changerIdentity = identityService.ReadIdentities(
    requestContext,
    new List<IdentityDescriptor> {
        IdentityHelper.CreateDescriptorFromSid(workItemChangedArgs.ChangerSid)
    },
    QueryMembership.Expanded,
    null).Single();
if (!IdentityHelper.IsServiceIdentity(requestContext, changerIdentity)) {
    // Do stuff….
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this sounds like a better idea. Frankly, I'm having a hard time believing that I didn't consider it (this was a long time ago and my memory is fuzzy), I wonder if I ran into some sort of problem or gotcha... I'll have to revisit the code and see if I can refactor it as you describe.